# How can I show print statements in debug mode of OPNET Modeler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm writing C++ code in OPNET Modeler.
I try to simulate my scenario in debugger mode & I need to trace the function that I wrote it. I need to show print statements which I put it in my code.

I used in debugger mode: `***ltr function_name()***` then `***c***`

But the result looks like:

```
Type 'help' for Command Summary


ODB> ltr enqueue_packet()
Added trace #0: trace on label (enqueue_packet())

ODB> c
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Progress: Time (1 min. 52 sec.); Events (500,002)                           |
| Speed: Average (82,575 events/sec.); Current (82,575 events/sec.)           |
| Time : Elapsed (6.1 sec.)                                                   |
| DES Log: 28 entries                                                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Progress: Time (1 min. 55 sec.); Events (1,000,002)                         |
| Speed: Average (69,027 events/sec.); Current (59,298 events/sec.)           |
| Time : Elapsed (14 sec.)                                                    |
| DES Log: 28 entries                                                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Progress: Time (1 min. 59 sec.); Events (1,500,002)                         |
| Speed: Average (51,464 events/sec.); Current (34,108 events/sec.)           |
| Time : Elapsed (29 sec.)                                                    |
| DES Log: 28 entries                                                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Simulation Completed - Collating Results.                                   |
| Events: Total (1,591,301); Average Speed (48,803 events/sec.)               |
| Time  : Elapsed (33 sec.); Simulated (2 min. 0 sec.)                        |
| DES Log: 29 entries                                                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Reading network model.                                                      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I need to show the print statements in my code.
Where it has to be appeared?
Is there any step before run the simulation to insure that OPNET debugger using Visual Studio & go through my code??

Answer (score 2):

OPNET Modeler provides the following commands to print trace output:

op_prg_odb_print_major()  Prints a sequence of strings to the standard output device, in the format of ODB trace statements starting at the major indentation level.

op_prg_odb_print_minor()  Prints a sequence of strings to the standard output device, in the format of ODB trace statements at the minor indentation level.

op_prg_text_output()  Prints a sequence of user-defined strings to the standard output device.

For example:

```
if (op_prg_odb_ltrace_active ("tcp_window")) {
  /* a trace is enabled, output Window-Related Variables */
  char str0[128], str1[128], str2[128];
  sprintf (str0, "rcv requests pending : (%d)", num_rcvs_allowed);
  sprintf (str1, "local receive window : (%d)", receive_window);
  sprintf (str2, "remote receive window : (%d)", remote_window);
  op_prg_odb_print_major ("Window-Related Variables", str0, str1, str2, OPC_NIL);

  sprintf (str0, "send unacked : (%d)", send_unacked);
  sprintf (str1, "send_next : (%d)", send_next);
  sprintf (str2, "receive next : (%d)", receive_next);
  op_prg_odb_print_minor (str0, str1, str2, OPC_NIL);
}
```

Example output as it appears on the standard output device:

```
            |       Window-Related Variables
            |               rcv requests pending : (3)
            |               local receive window : (6400)
            |               remote receive window : (10788)
            |               send unacked : (4525)
            |               send_next : (5000)
            |               receive_next : (1200)
```

[Code taken from OPNET Modeler documentation.]

Note:  I am guessing that you are modifying the standard models and are using the stdmod Repository.  If this is the case, your code is not being compiled and you will not see any print statements in the debugger.  See preference "Network simulation Repositories" to see if you are using a repository instead of compiling your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about what your trying to do , but i think you can output statements directly to a debugger for C++ code using

`OutputDebugStringA("Your string here");`

or just

`OutputDebugString("Your string here");`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used theses 2 statements in my code but there is no any message appeared in debug mode.

I used this statements also op_sim_message ("**Hello**", "Hello");
and I didn't get any message in debug mode.
plz help me

Comment: Did you try adding the above statement where your sure your code will run?

Comment: yes, I add OutputDebugString("Your string here"); op_sim_message ("Hello", "Hello"); at the beginning of my code to insure that debugger go through my code but there is no any messages appeared!!! please anyone help me.