# How can I show print statements in debug mode of OPNET Modeler

Tags: visual-c++

I'm writing C++ code in OPNET Modeler. I try to simulate my scenario in debugger mode & I need to trace the function that I wrote it. I need to show print statements which I put it in my code.

Comment: i tried a simple statement printf("  ");

Answer (score 1):

You can use Printf statements like in C wherever you want to trace.

The Sample output for a QoS network using OPNET:

Transmitting data at 581.922628 by voice_sender_0....
Data received by voice_rx_0 at 581.923657.....
Ack is sent at 581.923667 by node: voice_rx_0...

If you don't see printf statements on console then its the error in process model....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [op_prg_odb_print_major()](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static//doc/opnet/17.5.A/online/modeler_17.5_PL5/Programmers%20Reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=03_40_Prg.27.57.html#65309&single=true) or the [op_prg_odb_print_minor()](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static//doc/opnet/17.5.A/online/modeler_17.5_PL5/Programmers%20Reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=03_40_Prg.27.58.html#65433&single=true) for print messages via OPNET debug mode. And also further info on labelled breakpoints with: [op_prg_odb_bkpt()](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static//doc/opnet/17.5.A/online/modeler_17.5_PL5/Programmers%20Reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=03_40_Prg.27.53.html&single=true).

Comment: my problem that all statement of printf doesn't show up on my opnet debugger for example : printf("hello world");

Comment: The printf statement isn't supported by the ODB, from what I have found. There is additional support for my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052485/how-can-i-show-print-statements-in-debug-mode-of-opnet-modeler

Comment: I saw that before and i didn't get my answer ,thanks.

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you.